# Update Location on Interval

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

This is the current code I have to show the last known good location as a marker on a Google Map. All is functional, but I'd like to update the location on an interval (say 1 minute or 5 minutes.) What is the best way to implement this given the current code I'm using?

```
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Parking extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private GoogleMap map;

    Button b;

    public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.parking);

        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (map!=null)
        {       

        //Set Map Type
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        //Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        //Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        //Get the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        //Get Current Location
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        //Get Lat/Long of the current location
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        //Create a latLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        //Show the current location in Google Map
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        //Zoom to location
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));

        //Add marker
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .title("You Are Here")
        );




        }//end if map !null
    }
```

Comment: did you tried the Fused Locations provider ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the requestLocationUpdates methods of the LocationManager class - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

You can specify the time interval in millis and also the minimum distance change in meters.

My suggestion is to switch to the newest Location API as explained here: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Comment: Being new, took me awhile to figure this out, but turns out it wasn't so complicated after all. Since I already had a button to click before saving the new information I wanted, I just implemented this method and extended LocationListener to the Activity. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

With the new introduced Fused Location Providers from Google it is much easier to get the location or to get periodic updates ! See this link which might be very helpful

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

All you need is too import google-play services to you project,

and also you may use a background service to get periodic updates.

```
public class UpdateLocation extends Service
        implements
            GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            LocationListener {

private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 300000;
private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 60000;
private LocationRequest lr;
private LocationClient lc;
private Location l;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    lr = LocationRequest.create();
    lr.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    lr.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    lr.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    lc = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
}


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    lc.connect();

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
 //do updates on Location change.
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.d("AutoTracker : Test", "Location Client Connected");
    if (updates) {
        lc.requestLocationUpdates(lr, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (lc.isConnected()) {
        lc.removeLocationUpdates(this);
    }
    lc.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: This looks most logical to me. How would I implement this into the above code? Would I replace the last known good location with a call to something in this class? How would I retrieve the lat/Lng?

Comment: http://hastebin.com/fomequyawe.avrasm, try this code, made of your code, kindly accept the answer if it helped !

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I received several errors with the code you provided, though it was partially helpful for me in creating a solution.